# Convert mySql query result to json using python

Tags: python, mysql, json

I want to monitor mySql Database for getting update of it's performance so I executed a query `show global status;` This gives me a list of varibale like `Uptime, aborted_connections` etc.

But I want to export the result in a json format, can I achieve that using python script?

What I have done till now is,

1. exported result of query to .csv file .
2. Trying to convert that csv file to json using the following python code

> ```
>  import csv
> import json
> csvfile = open ('./tempp/op.csv','r')
> jsonfile = open('./tempp/op.json','w')
> fieldnames = ("Variable_name","Value")
> reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile,fieldnames)
> for row in reader:
>   json.dump(row,jsonfile)
>   jsonfile.write('\n')
> ```

Issues:

1. The above script is not giving the desired result.It produces json like

> ```
> {"Value": null, "Variable_name": "Variable_name\tValue"}
> {"Value": null, "Variable_name": "Aborted_clients\t0"}
> {"Value": null, "Variable_name": "Aborted_connects\t7"}
> {"Value": null, "Variable_name": "Binlog_cache_disk_use\t0"}
> {"Value": null, "Variable_name": "Binlog_cache_use\t0"}
> {"Value": null, "Variable_name": "Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use\t0"}
> {"Value": null, "Variable_name": "Binlog_stmt_cache_use\t0"}
> ```

2. This seems to be a bad approach to first write the result to a file and then read data from it. Is there any better approach to directly convert result from mySql query to json object directly?

`Edit` based on answers:
My op.csv file looks like:

```
Variable_name   Value
Aborted_clients 0
Aborted_connects    7
Binlog_cache_disk_use   0
Binlog_cache_use    0
Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use  0
Binlog_stmt_cache_use   0
Bytes_received  31075
Bytes_sent  1891186
Com_admin_commands  445
Com_assign_to_keycache  0
Com_alter_db    0
Com_alter_db_upgrade    0
```

Comment: Hi mate, I think the main issue with your parse failures is that file you're calling "CSV" (comma separated values) is in fact "TSV" (tab separated values).

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try buddy-

```
import csv
import json

rows = []
with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        rows += [row]

print json.dumps(rows, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

The arguments in the json.dumps are just so the output is formatted nicely.

So, for an input of the following-

```
Heading1,Heading2,Heading3
Row1Value1,Row1Value2,Row1Value3
Row2Value1,Row2Value2,Row2Value3
Row3Value1,Row3Value2,Row3Value3
```

You should get this-

```
[
    {
        "Heading1": "Row1Value1",
        "Heading2": "Row1Value2",
        "Heading3": "Row1Value3"
    },
    {
        "Heading1": "Row2Value1",
        "Heading2": "Row2Value2",
        "Heading3": "Row2Value3"
    },
    {
        "Heading1": "Row3Value1",
        "Heading2": "Row3Value2",
        "Heading3": "Row3Value3"
    }
]
```

Comment: If you want to go to JSON straight from MySQL, you'll need to pull down a MySQL module using PIP and get to the point where you're executing that query with Python- I think it'll return a list of tuples.

Comment: Thanks, Edward. I have updated my question to show you how my csv file looks like. I am getting `{
        "Variable_name\tValue": "Com_alter_db_upgrade\t0"
    }` as json while I was expecting `{Com_alter_db_upgrade: 0}`.

Comment: BTW. I am able to successfully pull down json from mysql query directly. I am posting the script in answers to help future users.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas is very flexible library for data. You can download it here: [LINK](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas)

once you have it:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io import sql
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
e = pd.read_sql('select * from my_table;',conn)
b = e.to_json()

print(b)
```

I am working with sqlite3, but it is universal for all sqls i guess.

there is as well function: `pd.read_sql_table` to read direct from table, however you would need alchemy.

Answer (score 1):

Posting solution to my own question to help future visitors of this page:

Use following script to convert the result of `mySql` query output to JSON and save it to a file.

But before that install mySql connector:

```
sudo pip install MySQL-python
```

and the use following script.

```
import MySQLdb
import json

conn = MySQLdb.connect(host = "localhost", user="root", passwd="your_password_here")

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SHOW GLOBAL STATUS")

rs = cursor.fetchall()

result = dict(rs)

with open('result.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(result, f)
```